# Is there a correction for samples from a (linear) Prophet model when trained on an inhomogenous Poisson point process?

Tags: forecasting, data-transformation, poisson-process, point-process, prophet

[Facebook's Prophet](https://peerj.com/preprints/3190/) is a popular modelling choice for time series forecasting in production due to many steps being automated (and thus convenient). This can sometimes lead to over-reliance on it when there are more reasonable mathematical alternatives.

One example that can arise is when the true data-generating process is an inhomogenous Poisson point process, which can be substantially non-normal for low arrival rates. While Poisson distributions approximate Normal distributions for large arrival rates, let us suppose that the arrival rates of interest are small enough that the asymptotic approximation does not hold acceptably well (i.e. don't use it to answer this question).

Suppose a Prophet model is trained on such a process, with no additional regressors (beyond its holiday effects, trend and change points in trend, and Fourier Series) and that the model specification would have been correct had a Poisson likelihood been chosen instead of a normal likelihood in Prophet, but the normal likelihood was used anyway. Take as a constraint that we cannot train the correctly-specified model, but we can obtain 10 000 pseudorandom samples from the trained Prophet model.

Is there a correction to convert such a pseudorandom sample into approximately (in distribution) the sample that would have obtained if we had used a "Poisson Prophet" model?

Comment: A naïve guess at obtaining natural numbers (including zero) is to compute $$\left \lfloor{ \max (X_t, 0) }\right \rfloor$$ but I cannot say *a priori* how far off this change of variables would be.